# Radical/Prime/Maximal ideals under quotient maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring (commutative with unity) $R$ and let $q:R\to R/I$ be the quotient map. Then there is a well known correspondence between ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and ideals of $R/I.$

Let $J$ be an ideal of $R$ containing $I$ and let $J'$ be the corresponding ideal in the quotient ring. I had to show that $J$ is radical/prime/maximal iff $J'$ is radical/prime/maximal.

Showing $J$ is radical/prime/maximal if $J'$ is was simple enough by direct element manipulation arguments.

For the other direction, I did it by using $J'=J/I,$ the fact that ideals are radical/prime/maximal iff their quotient rings are reduced/domains/fields and the second isomorphism theorem. However, I tried unsuccessfully to find a "direct" proof that perhaps manipulates elements of the ring in a similar way to the other direction. Is there a more direct proof? I'm wondering this especially for the radical ideals, because this is Exercise 1.22 (page 7) in Fulton's [Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and he has never even mentioned reduced rings or nilradicals yet, and doesn't expect you to know it already because he introduced what radical ideals were.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually already proved the difficult part.

If $J$ is maximal, then by the correspondence of ideals you mention $J'$ has to be maximal, too. If it weren't, there would be a proper ideal $T'\supset J'$, which would give a proper ideal $T\supset J$.

Now assume $J$ prime and let $a'b'\in J'$, where $a',b'$ are the classes in $R/I$ of some $a,b\in R$. This means that there are $i_a,i_b\in I$ such that $(a+i_a)(b+i_b)=ab+ai_b+bi_a+i_ai_b\in J+I=J$, as $I\subseteq J$. Thus $ab\in J$ and, say, $a\in J$. Hence $a'\in J'$, so $J'$ is prime.

Finally, suppose $J$ radical and let $(a')^r\in J'$ for some $a\in R$, $r\in\Bbb N$. Then there are some $i_a,i\in I$ such that, by binomial expansion and since $I$ is an ideal, $(a+i_a)^r=a^r+i\in J+I=J$. Hence $a^r\in J$, so $a\in J$. Therefore $a'\in J'$ and $J'$ is radical.

Answer (score -1):

For $J$ prime (maximal, resp.), we have an  isomorphism $R/J = (R/I)/(J/I)$, then $J$ prime (maximal) if and only if $R/J$ is an integer ring (field), if and only if $J/I$ is prime(maximal).

For $J$ radical, use that the radical of $J$ is the intersection of all prime ideals contains $J$, hence contains $I$, and above statements.