# Maximal ideals of the ring $\frac{K[X,Y]}{\langle XY\rangle}$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let's assume that we're working with commutative rings with unit and $K$ a field.

I want to compute the maximal ideals of the ring $\frac{K[X,Y]}{\langle XY\rangle}$. I'm given as a hint that every ideal of $K[X,Y]$ is finitely generated?.

So my question is double:

1. Why every ideal of $K[X,Y]$ is finitely generated?.
2. Can you give me a strategy to show what are the maximal ideals of $\frac{K[X,Y]}{\langle XY\rangle}$?

**Edit**

Reid's page 22 tells what are the maximal ideals of $K[X,Y]$

There is a lemma I think that may be useful, any element of $\frac{K[X,Y]}{\langle XY\rangle}$ can be expressed in a unique way as $k+F_1(X)X+F_2(Y)Y$

Comment: Your question is a good example as I realize I said something wrong. $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$ really means $R/I$ is an integral domain. If $ab= 0$ and $a \not \in I, b \not\in I$ then $a+I,b+I$ are zero divisors in $R/I$. Thus a prime ideal must contain, for each pair $ab=0$ of zeros divisors, one of $a$ or $b$. And hence the ideal generated by all the zero divisors can be written as a sum of two prime ideals (not necessary in a unique way)

Comment: 1) This is often given as a corollary of the Hilbert Basis Theorem.  2) Use the lattice isomorphism theorem: the ideals of $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ are bijection with the ideals of $K[X,Y]$ that contain $(XY)$.

Comment: @Rodrigo The maximal ideals containing $X$ are in bijection with the maximal ideals of $K[X,Y]/(X)\simeq K[Y]$ which are the irreducible polynomials of $K[Y]$. To conclude, these are of the form $(X,f(Y))$ with $f$ irreducible. (The other ones are clear.)

Comment: $K$ isn't just any commutative ring because for the ideals of $K[X,Y]$ to be finitely generated, $K$ has to be at least Noetherian. If you're looking at maximal ideals in polynomial rings, you're usually looking at $K$ to be an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea for the second question: there exists [a natural correspondence between the ideals of $R$ and the ideals of $R/I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346275/radical-prime-maximal-ideals-under-quotient-maps), in general: if $p : R \to R/I$ is the natural projection, then $p(J)$ is a (maximal) ideal in $R/I$ if and only if $J$ is a (maximal) ideal in $R$ and $J \supseteq I$. Applying this, the maximal ideals of $K[X,Y] / \langle XY \rangle$ are the images of the maximal ideals of $K[X,Y]$ that contain $\langle XY \rangle$. Again, without knowing more about $K$, it is difficult to tell what are the maximal ideals of $K[X,Y]$.

Comment: For principal ideals $(a)(b)= \{ cd, c \in (a), d \in (b)\} = (ab)$. But here we can't use the CRT because $(X,Y) \ne (1)$

Comment: In abstract-algebra we use $K$ for fields. @user26857 If $(I,J)$ is a maximal ideal, can't we modify the CRT to obtain something like $R/IJ  \cong R/I \otimes_{R/(I,J)} R/J$ ?

Comment: @reuns I don't think so.